# npm install -g generator-jhipster Windows issue with python

Tags: jhipster

I really have now to install Python on Windows to use jhipster ??? 

One month ago there was no issue with python.

```
D:\Perso\missa>npm install -g generator-jhipster
-


> fidonet-mailer-binkp-crypt@0.0.21 install C:\Users\A10282\AppData\Roaming\npm
node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\down
oad\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\decompress-unzip\node_modules\adm-zip\
ode_modules\fidonet-mailer-binkp-crypt
> node-gyp configure build

\
C:\Users\A10282\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_module
\yeoman-generator\node_modules\download\node_modules\decompress\node_modules\de
ompress-unzip\node_modules\adm-zip\node_modules\fidonet-mailer-binkp-crypt>node
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\
ode-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure build
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PY
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\no
e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nod
-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.:99:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_mod
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\A10282\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipste
\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\download\node_modules\decompress\no
e_modules\decompress-unzip\node_modules\adm-zip\node_modules\fidonet-mailer-bin
p-crypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "generator-jhipster"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fidonet-mailer-binkp-crypt@0.0.21 install: `node-gyp configure build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fidonet-mailer-binkp-crypt@0.0.21 install script 'node-g
p configure build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fidonet-mailer-binkp-crypt pack
ge,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fidonet-mailer-binkp-crypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Perso\missa\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of a new dependency in the adm-zip package:
https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/issues/121

Workaround: npm install --save-dev --save-exact adm-zip@0.4.4